# distances of the end points of two orthogonal line segments

Tags: geometry, inequality

I have two line segments (with the same length) which are positioned on two orthogonal lines (see figure 1). For an application I would like to show that $(b-a)-d<0.5d$. It's easy to see that its true for the special cases $2)$ and $3)$.

For $2)$ we have $a=0$ and $b=d\sqrt{2}$. Therefore we get: \begin{align}(b-a)-d=d\sqrt{2}-d<0.5d\end{align}

For $3)$we have that the distance of the segments to the "origin" is the same. So we have $b=a+2x$ and $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}d$ and we get:  \begin{align}(b-a)-d=(a+\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}d-a)-d=d\sqrt{2}-d<0.5d\end{align}

For the general case $1)$ I have no idea if my claim is true and how I could show it. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true.

To see why let us denote by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the angles between $b$ and the two $d$-segments. We have

$$
b \leq a + d(\cos(\alpha) + \cos(\beta))
$$

Since $\alpha+\beta = \pi/2$ we have $\cos(\beta) = \sin(\alpha)$. Thus, by the trigonometric pythagorean theorem, denoting $x:=\cos(\alpha)$ we have $x+\sqrt{1-x^2} = \cos(\alpha) + \cos(\beta)$. Hence

$$
b \leq a + d\cdot (x+\sqrt{1-x^2})
$$

where $x$ is allowed to range between $0$ and $1$. Therefore

$$
b - a - d \leq d\cdot (x+\sqrt{1-x^2}-1) =: d\cdot f(x).
$$

We have to show that $f(x) < 1/2$. Clearly $f(0)=f(1)=0$. We can find the possible extremal points by taking the derivative and setting it equal to zero. This yields $x=1/\sqrt{2}$ as the sole extremal (maximal) point. Hence

$$
f(x) \leq f(1/\sqrt{2}) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} - 1 < 1/2
$$

and the claim is proved.

Comment: Thanks! I will mark this as the answer. I can't see any faults and it's a really nice proof!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,y $ be $x,y$ components of $a$, then we want to show that
$f(d) = \sqrt{(d+x)^2+(d+y)^2} - \sqrt{x^2+y^2} - {3 \over 2} d $ satisfies 
$f(d) \le 0 $ for $d \ge 0$. Clearly $f(0) = 0$.

Grinding through the details we have
$f'(d) = {x+d + y+d \over \sqrt{(d+x)^2+(y+d)^2} }-{3 \over 2}$, and
since $\|y\|_1 \le \sqrt{2}\|y\|_2$, we have
$f'(d) \le \sqrt{2}-{3 \over 2} < 0$ and so $f'(d) \le 0$ for all $d \ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Outline**

Let the coordinates of the leftmost point be $A(0,0)$ and the coordinates of the vertex of the square be $B(x,0)$. Then the point $D(d,0)$ lies on the line $AB$. Similarly, let the coordinates of the rightmost point be $C(x,-y)$. Then the point $E(x,d-y)$ lies on the line $BC$. Therefore, $$a=|DE|=\sqrt{(x-d)^2+(d-y)^2},\quad b=|AC|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ so your statement is equivalent to \begin{align}b-a-d<0.5d&\impliedby b-a<1.5d\\&\impliedby\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-\sqrt{(x-d)^2+(d-y)^2}<1.5d\\&\impliedby x^2+y^2<\left(1.5d+\sqrt{(x-d)^2+(d-y)^2}\right)^2\\&\impliedby x^2+y^2<2.25d^2+3d\sqrt{(x-d)^2+(d-y)^2}+2d^2-2d(x+y)+x^2+y^2\\&\impliedby4.25d+3\sqrt{(x-d)^2+(d-y)^2}-2(x+y)>0\\&\impliedby\cdots\end{align}